# Search for file Google Drive API

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I am having problems finding a file using the Google Drive API. I set up a service account so not sure if that makes a difference. My code is below and all I get at the moment is `undefined` returned. I would also like to search within specific folders but can't seem to find this option anywhere?

```
// Check File exists
drive.files.list({
   auth: jwtClient,
   spaces: 'drive',
   q: "name='liverpool_away.xlsx'",
   pageSize: 10,
   fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
}, function(err, response) {
   if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);// outputs The API returned an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
      return;
   }

   var files = response.files;
   console.log("Files: " + files); // outputs undefined
   if (files.length == 0) {
      console.log('No files found.');
   } else {
      console.log('Files:');
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
         var file = files[i];
         console.log('%s (%s)', file.name, file.id);
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: where does the `undefined` value appears (which line number) ? Is it with `err` or within the loop ?

Comment: updated question with outputs

Comment: think i got it figured out, i have to use `response.data.files` not `response.files` even though the docs do say `response.files`

Comment: Hi Richlewis, can you figure out why we need to specify the ".data" part in code ?